# How to Show Foreign Key data in Django rest framework?

Tags: django, api, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

**Model:**

```
class Demo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    desc = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Serializer:**

```
class DemoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Demo
        fields = '__all__'
```

I have form in frontend side where I'm adding `name, desc and assigning to User` so here I'm getting on an issue.

I'm passing data to API `{name: "demo", desc: "lorem ipsum", user: 1 }`
It's working on save but after saving it's return same response but I want user **`first_name, last_name, and email`** in return response.

Because I have a table showing a list of demo table content. but always getting only `User ID` not a detail of user.

If I'm increasing `depth` of `Serializer` It's creating an issue in save time but on get records time I'm getting all details of `User` model. Like Password also in response so that is a security issue for me show all thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could separate the Create and Retrieve serializer. For example, the create serializer will be the one you are currently using:

```
class DemoCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Demo
        fields = '__all__'
```

On the other hand, Retrieve serializer will serialize the User with a different serializer using [Nested Relationship](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships).

```
class DemoRetrieveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserMinimalSerializer # or you could use your UserSerializer, see the last part of the answer
    class Meta:
        model = Demo
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'desc', 'user')
        read_only = ('id', 'name', 'desc', 'user',)
```

In your view, you will create the data with the first serializer and respond with the second. An example using `APIView`:

```
class DemoView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        create_serializer = DemoCreateSerializer(data=request.data)
        if create_serializer.is_valid():
            instance = create_serializer.save()
            retrive_serializer = DemoRetrieveSerializer(instance)
            return Response(retrive_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(create_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

You might have to customize DRF provided views to achieve this, i.e. for [Generic views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/).

Since you don't want to include *all the fields* of User model, you will have to write a minimal representation of User using another serializer.

```
class UserMinimalSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
        read_only = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email',)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `depth = 1` to get all the data of foreign key object:

```
class DemoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Demo
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```